# Kivy - Set value of checkbox

Tags: python, kivy

How can I set value of checkbox from code.
I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
self.checkbox.active = True #not working
```

Thanks

Comment: `self.checkbox.state = "down" #checked` --- 
`self.checkbox.state = "normal" #unchecked`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me, do I need to declare state in kv. file in my checkbox?

Comment: Ok it worked, I was calling function with it at wrong time. Thank you